# typescript moduleResolution nodenext and importing tsx file

Tags: typescript, docusaurus

I have to import a custom package export and for that, I had to set the moduleResolution to node16 or nodenext as per [3307](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079). Once I did this, the import path is recognized. However, I now have a new warning

"Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in EcmaScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './some-tsx-file.js'?ts(2835)"

when I have

```
import('some-tsx-file')
```

If i use 'some-tsx-file.js' my build (based on docusaurus) fails that there is no such file and if I use 'some-tsx-file.tsx' I get yet another warning

"An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing './some-tsx-file' instead.ts(2691)"

So what is the way to get around these and make both typescript and the build process happy?